# Any (or best) way to get records from CloudKit that aren't on the device?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cloudkit

I have the following predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (recordID in %@)", recordIDs)
-- recordIDs is an array of CKRecordID objects corresponding to the CKRecords on the device
```

...that produces a runtime error about the predicate. If I change the predicate format string to something else, the query runs fine. I have the "Query" checkbox checked for all the metadata for this record type in CloudKit.

According to [CKQuery documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKQuery):

> Key names used in predicates correspond to fields in the currently evaluated record. Key names may include the names of the record’s metadata properties such as "creationDate” or any data fields you added to the record.

According to [CKRecord documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014044-CH1-SW14), these are the available metadata for querying:

> recordID, recordType, creationDate, creatorUserRecordID, modificationDate, lastModifiedUserRecordID, recordChangeTag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the creation date:

```
NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", dateLastFetched)
```

After you pull the records down to the device and save them, save the dateLastFetched and use it for subsequent fetches.

Edit: Be sure to enable the creationDate query index on the CloudKit dashboard (it is not enabled by default like many other indexes)

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Have you seen or been able to query using any of the other metadata?

Comment: @user3071284 I use this same predicate, but with modificationDate instead of creationDate.

Comment: @user3071284 The one piece of metadata I have tried and been unable to use is the exact one you tried to use: recordID. That is not allowed because you are supposed to use CKFetchRecordsOperation for record IDs

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so I'm not sure if it existed at the time, but the correct way to do this now is to use Apple's built-in **server change token** support.

Making a giant query including all existing record ID's on the device is going to be slow, and picking a date is going to be imprecise.

The right way to do this is to use `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` and pass in a `CKServerChangeToken` using the operation's `configurationsByRecordZoneID` property.

The first time you call, pass a `nil` change token. As records are received, CloudKit will call `recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock` with the latest change token. Persist the latest token so the next time you need records from the server, you can just pass in your most recent token and get only what's changed since then.

Comment: This is a nice API, but it can be extremely slow when the change history of the data if long. In that case using CKQuery is often much faster.

Comment: "Extremely slow"? Mmm, not really. It will return exactly one copy of any record that's been changed or added since the last fetch - not the entire change history. It's also very fast in practice, has the benefit of returning a list of deleted records since the last checkpoint, and is Apple's recommended way to retrieve the latest changes from the cloud. Querying for a long list of record ID's is a premature attempt at optimization. You can bet Apple optimizes the "fetch changes" operation to the max, since it's the recommended way of getting the latest changes.

Comment: CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation is indeed fast and very useful when the change history is not too large and not too old. But when you start such operation without a token, it's far from optimised to download an initial large dataset (> 20.000 rows) with a long change history in a reasonable amount of time. In my experience using CKQueryOperation (which is btw not the same as fetching record id's with CKFetchRecordsOperation) is at least 5x faster. This article from Jaanus Kase describes what I mean: https://www.justtact.com/blog/three-methods-of-retrieving-records-from-cloudkit

Comment: @Ely I just read the article. All I can say is that hasn't been my experience at all. I don't have performance issues with fetching record changes, even when I'm just starting with a nil token, even with large binary assets in my records.

Comment: @Ely I think this is the issue: "Do you just not keep historic data in your app at all, so that all retrieving would be for a reasonably recent period, and CKFRZCO would be fast? This has many benefits, sure. Do it if you can. Less data is less pain. In Tact, though, we currently keep all the history. And there’s nothing in CloudKit philosophy or guidance which would say we shouldn’t do that. As far as we can tell, CloudKit is suitable for keeping data over long periods of time, and most of it works well in this case. CKFRZCO is the one notable exception." It's their data model.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the meta data index by clicking here:

[image]